# yum install proftpd error

Tags: yum, centos5, ftp

I used proftpd for years on this year.  but I got an error when I update proftpd today.    I am using CentOS 5.11.

```
[root@server11 yum.repos.d]# yum install proftpd

Dependencies Resolved

========================================================================================================================================
 Package                         Arch                           Version                              Repository                    Size
========================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 proftpd                         x86_64                         1.3.3g-4.el5                         epel                         3.6 M


Running Transaction
  Installing     : proftpd                                                                                                          1/1 
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.71056: line 5: [: too many arguments
(repeated 50 lines)

Installed:
  proftpd.x86_64 0:1.3.3g-4.el5                                                                                                         

Complete!
```

However, I cannot connect to the server.  it keeps saying my password is incorrect.
530 login incorrect

Comment: IIRC the default configuration only supports anonymous FTP and enabling FTP for local users requires some changes.

Comment: The default config in CentOS allows local users in a chroot. @hatted Can you reinstall proftpd? (yum erase, yum install)

Answer (score 1):

I tried a few repo but none of them works.  So finally I install it from rpm which I download from http://pkgs.repoforge.org/proftpd/